# Android. How to get audio file format?

Tags: java, android, file, audio, format

Is there any way to get a format of a local audio file by given uri or file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a page describing various techniques of how to get the mime-type of a file:

- http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html